# getResourceAsStream() finds resource, but it will write an empty file

Tags: java, resources, inputstream

I have a .properties File located in my resource folder. I would like to load the file but when I'm using IOUtils to read the content of my file, it will just create a new empty file and won' copy the content of my test.properties.

```
    try (InputStream demoTemplate = 
          MyClass.class
         .getClassLoader()
         .getResourceAsStream("/config/test.properties")
    {
        IOUtils.copy(demoTemplate, new FileWriter(destinationFile));
        LOGGER.debug(" demo file content: " + OUtils.toString(demoTemplate));
    }
```

My logging output is empty, the File will be created but it has no content.

When I change the path of the test.properties file it will cause an `FileNotFound` exception so I'm sure the ClassLoader can load the respurce. The `test.properties` File contains data.

Comment: How do you run your application? What's in the classpath? Are you sure you are finding the right resource?

Comment: Its a deployed webapplication. This question is also answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logging output is empty because you have exhausted the `InputStream` into the destination file.

Your output could be empty because the `FileWriter` was never flushed or closed properly.

Perhaps you could read the destination file and log that, open the original source again, keep a copy of the input stream's contents, or log as you transfer the data, though that would require not using the simple `IOUtils` helper.

Comment: This doesn't explain why there won't be any data written to the destination file. IOUtils takes care about flushing as fas as I know.

Comment: after your edit I checked the FileWriter again. You are correct, you need to flush / close the FileWriter after IOUtils copied the data. Thanks